# How to do a Word Count in a list for Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that's in a structure like:

```
['Blah blah blah', 'blah blah blah', 'blah', 'blah blah']
```

(the user puts in inputs that make up the list, but I have already written the code for that)
I need to write a code that tells the user how many words there are in the list. In that specific list, there are 9 words, and I tried many ways, but I cannot seem to write the correct code. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Are the words always space separated?

Comment: Yes, the words are space separated.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that words are always separated by a single space, you can use the below code:

```
>>> words = ['Blah blah blah', 'blah blah blah', 'blah', 'blah blah']
>>> 
>>> sum(len(line.split()) for line in words)
9
```

Comment: This give wrong results with trailing/leading whitespace. I'd simply use `line.split()` without specifying the separator.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(len(x) for x in [w.split() for w in ['Blah blah blah', 'blah blah blah', 'blah', 'blah blah']])
=> 9
```

or shorter, as Eric suggests:

```
sum(len(x.split()) for x in ['Blah blah blah', 'blah blah blah', 'blah', 'blah blah'])
```

Comment: You should never need to write `f(x) for x in [g(y) for y in iterable]` - just use `f(g(y)) for y in iterable`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
thelist = ['Blah blah blah', 'blah blah blah', 'blah', 'blah blah']
wc = 0
for item in thelist:
    words = item.split()
    wc = wc + len(words)
print 'word count is %d.' % (wc)
```